# Access API using Service Account

Tags: nest-device-access

Does the Smart Device Management API support access using a Service Account?  If so what's the magic combo?

I can access the API using registered OAuth2, and get valid device list response.

When using Service Account credentials to access the device list API I get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Enterprise enterprises/{project-id} not found.",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and I've tried adding some role for IoT without solving...Did you find some solutions meantime?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that google have chosen to cut off the "home project" user. They seem to only support oauth2 auth and if you want to use it you have to get your app certified, otherwise they revoke the refresh token after 7 days. If the refresh token didn't get revoked every 7 days then I'd be happy with oauth2 offline auth.  Come on google, support the home hobbyists!